# Conversion of sql query into mongoDB query language

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

I am having a query in sql i.e "select ServiceName,count(_id) from cases groupby ServiceName,_id;"

I want to covert it into mongoDB query language. please help.

Comment: please show part of your previous attempt or research...

Comment: I didn't get you @kiyarash. Actually i am integrating mongoDB with jasper i-report.So as per my requirement of bar graph i need to execute the above query in mongoDB query language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to get familiar with mongodb docs, particularly the [sql to mongo mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/).

If you are just looking for a one-time quick-and-dirty solution though, check out [querymongo](http://www.querymongo.com/).